# creating a new directory each time a shell script is run on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to create a shell script that copies .log files from one directory to a new directory, with a new name each time the script is run.

For example lets say there's File1.log, File2.log, File3.log in `/home/usr/logs`

and when this script runs, I want them to be copied to a new location `/home/usr/savedlogs/Run1` and the next time it runs...`/home/usr/savedlog/Run2` and so on...

I'm not sure if this would be used:

> cp /home/usr/logs/{File1.log,File2.log,File3.log} /home/usr/savedlogs

I'm hoping this is possible in a shell script. Thank you all for your help in advance, greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you control the run count of the script? is it bound to run a finite number of times or not predicted ahead?

Comment: Well I'm calling an alias cplogs, which executes this script (ideally)

Comment: alias cplogs='./scriptname'

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple script that might suffice your requirement:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the number of Run* directories present
newnum=$(ls -ld /home/usr/savedlogs/Run* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)

mkdir -p /home/usr/savedlogs/Run${newnum}

cp /home/usr/logs/*.log /home/usr/savedlogs/Run${newnum}
```

This will start from `Run0` and proceeds from there

Comment: This will copy all the logs to the `Run[0-n]` folders in one shot, OP wants to  copy to a new folder per script run.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain the `/dev/null | wc -l)` part for me? I like to fully understand the code that I'm writing

Comment: @Inian: I am copying to `Run${newnum}` which will be only one directory every time the script is run.

Comment: @JH: `2>/dev/null` redirects the error message from `ls` if any to `/dev/null`. `wc -l` counts the number of lines present in the `ls -ld` output.

Comment: @JH: Try the new edited code. I included `-d` option to `ls`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about incrementing directory names, you can do this with a simple timestamp:

```
DIR=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
mkdir $DIR
cp /home/usr/logs/FileXXX.log /home/usr/savedlogs/$DIR/
```

This will work as long as your copy operation happens less than once a second.

Comment: This will be an option I consider. Thank you so much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `newDir=$(ls -l /home/usr/savedlogs | grep Run | wc -l)` for getting the existing number of directories.

So the whole script will look like this :

```
    newDir=$(ls -l /home/usr/savedlogs | grep Run | wc -l)
    mkdir -p /home/usr/savedlogs/Run${newDir}
    cp /home/usr/logs/*.log /home/usr/savedlogs/Run${newDir}
```

First folder will be `Run0`, next `Run1` and so on...